# Running the command "bochs -q" from Cygwin fails

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, shell, cygwin

I'm having troubles to execute the command "bochs -q" from Cygwin.

I have installed the XV6 operation system in my C drive.

I'm using Cygwin in order to compile the XV6 files, that is execute the command "make".

Everything works as expected and my XV6 directory is getting bigger including the compiled files.

Then, as I'm following instructions from the web (https://github.com/guilleiguaran/xv6), I was trying to execute the command "bochs -q" and I got the following error : "**bash: bochs: command not found**".

I also tried to execute the command "**make bochs**" which start executes perfectly fine but in the end fails for the same reason as above (**bochs: command not found**).

I can open bochs directly from the directory "**Program Files (x86)**" but I would prefer using the shell to do so.

Is it possible that I'm missing something?

**Note - I'm using Windows 7.**

Answer (score 0):

Type in 'which bochs' from the cygwin command line to see if you are finding it in your path. If it is not found then you will want to either add the full path location to your path (assuming you want that included in your path), or you will need to move it into a location already in your path.

Comment: Should I add the bochs exe file to the PATH where my XV6 is located?